# Rotas personalizadas Ghost Blog retornando erro "err_too_many_redirects"

Tags: blog

Eu estou trabalhando em um site de estudo utilizando o Ghost. A ideia é classificar os conteúdos de estudo em planos de leitura, utilizando como filtro tags específicas.

Dessa maneira eu agrupo dentro de um mesmo plano diversos artigos e a ideia é disponibilizar através da seguinte estrutura de url: `/planos/nome-do-plano/{slug}`.

Em `/planos/nome-do-plano/` serão renderizados todos os conteúdos relacionados ao plano de leitura em questão, enquanto que em `/planos/` serão renderizados todos os planos de leitura disponíveis no site.

Para isso eu configurei meu *routes.yaml* da seguinte forma:

```
routes:
  /planos/: plans
  /planos/os-tesouros-salmo-119/: plans-psalm-119
  /planos/evangelho-de-joao/: plans-john
  /planos/malaquias-hoje/: plans-malachi

collections:
  /planos/malaquias-hoje/:
    permalink: /planos/malaquias-hoje/{slug}/
    filter: 'tag:malaquias-hoje'
    template: plans-malachi
    rss: false

  /planos/os-tesouros-salmo-119/:
    permalink: /planos/os-tesouros-salmo-119/{slug}/
    filter: 'tag:os-tesouros-do-salmo-119'
    template: plans-psalm-119
    rss: false

  /planos/evangelho-de-joao/:
    permalink: /planos/evangelho-de-joao/{slug}/
    filter: 'tag:evangelho-de-joao'
    template: plans-john
    rss: false

  /:
    permalink: /{slug}/
    template: index

taxonomies:
  tag: /{slug}/
  author: /autor/{slug}/
```

Como eu defini no *routes.yaml* que o permalink das tags será apenas `/{slug}/` no *redirects.json* eu direciono as tags correspondentes ao plano de leitura para sua a própria página (`/plano/nome-do-plano`).

```
[
  {
    "from": "/os-tesouros-do-salmo-119/" ,
    "to":  "/planos/os-tesouros-salmo-119/",
    "permanent": true
  },
  {
    "from": "/evangelho-de-joao/" ,
    "to":  "/planos/evangelho-de-joao/",
    "permanent": true
  },
  {
    "from": "/malaquias-hoje/" ,
    "to":  "/planos/malaquias-hoje/",
    "permanent": true
  }
]
```

Mas o único plano que funciona corretamente é o `/os-tesouros-salmo-119/` (que foi o primeiro a ser criado) todos os outros quando tento acessar a página principal do plano (`/plano/nome-do-plano/`) retorna o erro `"ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"`.

Vale ressaltar que somente a página principal do plano de leitura é afetada, os artigos publicados dentro dos planos de leitura (`/plano/nome-do-plano/artigo-01/`) que não estão acessíveis podem lidos normalmente.

E a url gerada é sempre algo parecido com isso: `http://localhost:2368/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/planos/evangelho-de-joao/.`